# Strange order in std::map with russian text

Tags: c++11, stl, stdmap

Easy map like this

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> container = {
    {"первый",{1}},
    {"второй",{2}},
    {"третий",{3}},
    {"четвертый",{ 4 }}
};

for (auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it)
{
    auto tt = it;
    // do smth
}
```

but in order second element (`{"второй",{2}},`) go first

[image]

and this is text dependent - for example if second element will be with english text "second" (`{"second",{2}},`) - order will be normal, and this will be second element in order.

Who can explain what happened, or this is just bug in VS 2017 version 15.3 ?

Comment: Remember that [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is a *sorted* container, it sorts on the key. And in the [Cyrillic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) в comes before п.

Comment: yes - exactly  ! Thank you !

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude of course the order of the alphabet in question and the order of corresponding Unicode codes (of whatever kind) may or may not bear any similarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case a better desigion will be

```
std::map<std::vector<int>,std::string> container = {
{{1},"первый"},
{{2},"второй"},
{{3},"третий"},
{{4},"четвертый"}
};
```

- so std::map will be automated sorted by number keys

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I forgott about that std::map is a sorted container, and key in my case was "первый" and "второй" - so by russian alphabet "второй" is first.

Working code look like:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>> container = {
    {"первый",{1}},
    {"второй",{2}},
    {"третий",{3}},
    {"четвертый",{ 4 }}
};
```

But remeber that unordered_map has no order guaranteed !

Comment: Working? In what sense? std::unnordered_map is *unordered*, that is, no order whatsoever is guaranteed.

Comment: In general question was why so strange order created - in this variant working as expected, but of course "no order whatsoever is guaranteed" - you are absolutly right ...